# Angular SVG manipulation does'nt work in IE10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, google-chrome, svg

I'm struggling with a simple SVG Image, where I try to update the color of two rectangles.
In Chrome they get updated, In IE(10) the reactangles are just black!

In my controller I'm setting the color via $scope.cvrColor=[random generated color code]

I've made this simple sample to illustrate my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/mvg123/td7py264/

My Controller:

```
function testController($scope, $timeout) {
        var test = updateSvg();

    function updateSvg() {

        $scope.startColor = getRandomColor();
        $scope.cvrColor = getRandomColor();


        $timeout(updateSvg, 1000);
    };

    function getRandomColor() {

        var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        var color = "";
        switch (true) {
            case (number < 3):
                color = "#808000";
                break;
            case (number > 3 && number < 8):
                color = "#666666";
                break;
            case (number > 8 && number < 12):
                color = "#ff0000";
                break;
            default: color = "#ffff00";
        }
        return color;
    }
```

}

Any hints out there?

/Best regards

Answer (score 0):

While your example should work, I have discovered that having expressions inside class or style is somewhat unreliable. It's better to use ng-class and ng-style. So in your case you can write:

```
<rect ng-style="{fill:startColor, fillOpacity:1}" ... />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c5ozbv52/

Answer (score 0):

You must use the angularjs directive "ng-style" :

```
ng-style="{fill:startColor,fillOpacity:1}"
```

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle